# How to do autoComplete textBox in MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, autocomplete

I've been trying to complete a requirement which has a textbox where I need to do a autoComplete functionality. I have a Model which has two properties, Name and Value. So, I am a list of CityNames and their Id's. So on entering the name, system should get the Id. I've been trying alot but din't found any solution. Could anyone help me please!!

Here is my Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult FillViewData(string term)
{
    List<City> list = new List<City>()
    {
        new City{ Name = "Vijay", Id = 1 },
        new City{ Name = "Ratan", Id = 2 },
        new City{ Name = "Payo", Id = 3 },
        new City{ Name = "Hari", Id = 4 },
        new City{ Name = "Krish", Id = 5 }
    };
    var CityName = (from N in list
                where N.Name.StartsWith(term)
                select new { N.Name });
    return Json(CityName, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

View:

```
@Html.TextBox("searchName", null,new { name = "txtSearch"})
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#txtSearch").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'Home/FillViewData',
            type: "POST",
            dataType: JSON,
            data: { Prefix: request.term },
            success: function (data) {
                response($.map(data, function (item) {
                    return { label: item.Name, value: item.Name };
                }))

            }
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: Your sending the data as `data: { Prefix: request.term },` therefore the parameter in the method must be `FillViewData(string prefix)`

Comment: Though I changed it to Prefix, it's not working. Am I missing anything??

Answer (score 0):

Change url format like this

url: '/Home/FillViewData',